# How can client add me as user/developer on their LinkedIn App?

Tags: linkedin-api

I have a client that has set up a LinkedIn app via their own LinkedIn Developers account. I was wondering if anyone new of a way for them to add me as a user to this app so that I can check its configuration?

I am not able to create my own LinkIn App, so am not able to test it out, plus I haven't seen any documentation online.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, just found there is an "Add team members" area.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).